# Проблема при загрузке изображений из папки DCIM в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, файловая-система

Доброго времени суток!

Есть класс при помощи которого считываются данные из папок в частном случае DCIM

```
fun loadPhoto(directory: String): List<String> {
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(directory)
    val photos: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory) {
        val images = dir.listFiles()
        if (images != null) {
            for (image in images) {
                if (image.isDirectory) {
                    loadPhoto(image.absolutePath)
                } else {
                    photos.add(image.absolutePath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return photos
}
```

Путь к папке задается при помощи

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
```

Файлы в папке имеются. Но во время выполнения при проверке условия выдает NULL.

Если же я задаю вручную:

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory((Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)),"hello.jpg")
```

То при тесте имя файла возвращает корректно...

Перерыл кучу различных сайтов, везде решение подобное моему.
В чем может быть проблема у меня?

В манифесте разрешения выставлены

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Всем кто что либо посоветует огромное спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В манифесте разрешения выставлены

Добавить разрешения в манифест **!=** получить их. Эти разрешения ещё нужно [запросить](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) у пользователя.